# Are there standard for Binary Search Tree methods?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am implementing a BST in C++ and I implemented Get(), Add(), Remove() and Contains() methods. I know that some containers have standards such as a stack has push() and pop() methods. But I couldn't find any document about BST's standard methods?

Are there standard methods (like an interface) or is it up to us?

Comment: A BST is actually a sorted set, you can check what the Java 7 API provides for TreeSet: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: `std::set` is, to a first approximation, a binary search tree. You could consider its interface for guidance.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that is actually heplful and I think this is the answer for me. I will do as you say.

Comment: This may be better suited on Programmers.StackExchange.com

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I considered that, as well. But I wanted an answer in a C++ fashion, if there are multiple standards exists.

Comment: There is no standard API or library for a Binary Search Tree in the C++ language.  There are containers that may be implemented as a BST, such as `std::set` and `std::map`, but the implementation is up to the compiler vendor.  As far as external (to the language) libraries go, there are no interface standards.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it is up to you. C++ does not define a standard interface for anything.

That said the STL does recycle accessor names.

Set and map are likely the most similar data structures to your BST.

Set uses `insert()`, `count()` tells you if a set contains an item, `erase()` removes an item.

Map uses `operator[]` (the square brackets) and `at()` to access and set elements, in addition to offering `insert()`. `erase()` is used to remove an element.

So, in this sense, there's some kind of standardization, but it's specific to the STL and those who emulate it. However, use of the STL is wide-spread, so if there was anything you'd want to emulate, that would be it.

Comment: I will do so. In the end, other users of the class will be familiar with STL containers.